# how to update mysql database column charset or collation with laravel?

Tags: laravel

This is my migration code. This is not working not changing column collation.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('product', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('hash_id')->collate('utf8mb4_bin')->change();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('product', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('hash_id')->collation('utf8mb4_bin')->change();
        });
    }
```